# How to update data attribite based on table tr id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to replace the text Content .

I have a table tr as shown below

```
  <tr id="1" cat_id="88" cat_name="INFY" style="cursor: move;">
         <td id="order_1" style="vertical-align: middle;">2</td>
         <td style="vertical-align: middle;"> <span><span id="span1">INFY<span><span> (8)</span></span></span></span></td>
         <td style="vertical-align: middle;">JAN 3</td>
         <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input class="new-checkbox updatecheckboxvalueindb" value="new_flag" type="checkbox" checked=""><span></span></label></td>
         <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCategoryname" data-categorid="1" data-catname="INFY" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary editcatclick"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a></td>
         <td width="20%"><a href="#" class=" btn btn-sm btn-danger deletecat"><i class="icon-trash"></i> </a></td>
      </tr>
```

Based on the tr id , i am replacing the content as shown below

```
 var trid = 1;
 var texttoreplace= 'HCLTECH'
 /$("#span"+trid).text(texttoreplace);
```

I am also storing data inside a data attribute as **data-catname="INFY"**
Could you please tell me how to replace this data attribute also ??

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/416/

Comment: replace attribute on what event?include all relevant code in OP instead of an external link. for demo use snippet of SO

Comment: You have asked 1000+ question still not learned to use Code snippet and relying on JSFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this, its working fine

```
$("#span"+trid).closest('tr').find('a').attr('data-catname', 'HCLTECH')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
$("#span"+trid).attr("cat_name",texttoreplace);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the span inside table like this

`$("#sort").find("#span"+trid).text(texttoreplace);`

The same way you can use for set attribute value also

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/419/)